# SubConsulta me separa los datos sql sever

Tags: sql, sql-server

tengo mi query:

```
select
(select SUM(cco.Valor) from Temp t where t.cod = cco.cod and cco.costo = 1 )as uno,
(select SUM(cco.Valor) from Temp t where t.cod = cco.cod and cco.costo = 2 )as dos,
(select SUM(cco.Valor) from Temp t where t.cod = cco.cod and cco.costo = 3 )as tres,
(select SUM(cco.Valor) from Temp t where t.cod = cco.cod and cco.costo = 4 )as cuatro

from  Cuenta cco
group by
cco.cod,
cco.costo
```

***que sea dinamica, con eso me refiero a que dentro de mis subconsultas pueda hacer mas filtros, como de fecha, rango de edades, todo es dentro de la subconsulta***

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

si lo quieres hacer a tu modo...

```
select 
(select SUM(cc.Valor) from Cuenta cc where cc.cod = cco.cod and cc.costo = 1  ) as uno,
(select SUM(cc.Valor) from Cuenta cc where cc.cod = cco.cod and cc.costo = 2 ) as dos,
(select SUM(cc.Valor) from Cuenta cc where cc.cod = cco.cod and cc.costo = 3) as tres,
(select SUM(cc.Valor) from Cuenta cc where cc.cod = cco.cod and cc.costo = 4) as cuatro

from  Cuenta cco
group by 
cco.cod
```

esa seria la manera..

Comment: En realidad, esta no debería ser la respueta aceptada. No es recomendable efectuar esta consulta de esta manera.

Comment: sugiere otra respuesta para ver cual es la mejor manera de hacer subconsultas, y querys dinamicas ajustables a mas filtros

Answer (score 4):

Hay varios puntos de mejora en tu código. El más importante es que estás agrupando por la columna `costo`, cuando en realidad no se necesita. Por otro lado, no hay necesidad de hacer una subquery por cada columna, para esto existe `SUM`:

```
SELECT  cod,
        SUM(CASE WHEN costo = 1 THEN valor END) uno,
        SUM(CASE WHEN costo = 2 THEN valor END) dos,
        SUM(CASE WHEN costo = 3 THEN valor END) tres,
        SUM(CASE WHEN costo = 4 THEN valor END) cuatro
FROM Cuenta
GROUP BY cod
;
```

Comment: cual es la direfencia con la que publico el siguiente

Comment: que con esta consulta se lee solo una vez la tabla en vez de 5?. Pero esto lo puedes ver fácilmente analizando el plan de ejecución de ambas consultas

Comment: @OP: Sencillez y mejor rendimiento.

Comment: bueno es una sub consulta, ahora dentro de esas subconsultas aun tengo que hacer mes filtrados, puedo hacerla en tu query ?

Comment: @R.Fernandez pues es bastante vago tu comentario, no sabría cómo responderlo sin entender lo que quieres hacer, la verdad

Comment: lo que pregunte es la base para filtros, puedo hacerlo ?

Comment: como decía, no sé a qué te refieres en particular, por lo que no puedo responderte sin más detalles

Comment: `(select SUM(cco.Valor) from Temp t where t.cod = cco.cod and cco.costo = 1 and cco.Fecha between '2017-01-015' and '2017-02-15')as uno,`

Comment: según entiendo simplemente habría que poner esa condición de fecha dentro de la expresión `CASE`

Comment: soy nuevo y estoy aprendien :(

Comment: Sospecho que está repitiendo la misma condición de fechas para cada una de sus subconsultas.  De ser el caso, solo necesita moverlo al `WHERE` de la consulta y la consulta será aun mas sencilla y eficiente.

Comment: @sstan ah, claro, creo que tienes razón